# using sql and php how can i insert same record in my database automatically in a fixed time of everyday?

Tags: php, sql

In one of my website i need to insert some row of data in my database every day at a fixed time. I want to do this automatically using sql and php.

How can i do this? please help me.

Comment: what database/dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your on a webhost, they often use the cPanel system, which has cron jobs build in. Go to the menu, or search for Cron Jobs and add one.

Use the line "php -q ScriptPath" (no quotes)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux system, look into setting up a cron job.

This will enable you to execute a php script that you specify at fixed time intervals.

http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use cronjob in linux server to do a autotask to run the file once a day

In windows there is also a builtin program called schedule yask that does the same so u can possibly write command .bat file to run a php file in CLI php or id remember if possible to run a specific web adress blabla.com/mussl.php to accomplish what u need..